# ListPointPlot3D colour based on another list

Tags: color, plotting

Suppose I have points

```
data = {{0,1,0},{0,0,1},{1,0,0},{0.2,0.8,0}};
```

And another array exists with

```
colours = {0.1,0.2,0.6,0.3};
```

I want to Plot a ListPointPlot3D of data, with colour of each point defined by colours.

I tried something like

```
Show[ListPointPlot3D[data], 
ColorFunction-> (ColorData["Rainbow"][#1] /@ colours)];
```

But was unsuccessful. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `Graphics3D[ {AbsolutePointSize@12, 
  Point[data, VertexColors -> (ColorData["Rainbow"] /@ colours)
   ]}
 ]`

Comment: Let me know if the linked topic does not fit your needs.

Comment: @Kuba thanks for the idea; is it not possible/much more difficult using ListPointPlot3D? I was hoping to retain the functionality of ListPointPlot3D...

Comment: For instance, use of BarLegends for the colours?

Comment: You can put `BarLegend["Rainbow"]` next to it? Inset or whatever?

Comment: Sweet, thanks for the hint @Kuba; I got it working using Legended[Graphics[...], BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {Min[colours],Max[colours]}}]]